# Routes not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm using CodeIgniter 1.9 to build a website.

I want http://myurl.com/index.php/user/profile/2 to take me to the Profile Page for the user with the id of 2.

My routes.php file looks like this.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['user/profile/(:num)'] = 'user/profile_view/$1';
```

My user.php file looks like this.

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    function profile_view($id)
    {
            $data = array();
        log_message("info", "I am in the profile_view method of user.php.");

        $this->load->view("templates/header", $data);
        $this->load->view("templates/footer", $data);
    }
}
```

The code is never making it to the log_message() function and it is throwing a 500 error that says exactly this...

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil the request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've been looking for several hours now with no luck.

Comment: Anything in apache/webserver logs? Are you using htaccess?

Comment: Sanity check: Does the unrouted URL work? `http://myurl.com/index.php/user/profile_view/2` I have doubt this issue is directly related to routing.

Comment: No, the unrouted URL doesn't work.  I was assuming it was a routing issue because other routes were working.  The code was getting to the routing fine (I put a log_message call in just before the routing).  However, it isn't getting to the controller.

Comment: I'm on my personal laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 with a standard apache, MySQL, PHP setup.  I've made no modifications to htaccess.  I've put the CodeIgniter code into the /var/www folder and am running the site by going to "http://localhost/index.php"

Comment: Make sure error reporting is on properly (in PHP.ini, in index.php, etc.). The 500 error is likely because of a PHP error. Check your error logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

The $data you pass is not initialize. Probably your error 500 comes from it. Before log_message, type this statement:

```
$data = array();
```

Tell us if you have an error after this correction.

Comment: I highly doubt that's it, at best it would trigger a PHP notice. (but good point anyways)

Comment: Yeah, it still fails.  I actually was setting $data but commented out everything except the bare necessities to make life easier to debug. Good catch.  I added "$data = array();" just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think your routing might be slightly off. Try this out:

```
$route['user/profile'] = 'user/profile_view';
```

Your User Controller should be able to see the incoming parameter from the URL just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those you pointed out the PHP error log.  It was a problem in my Model code.  I apparently hadn't completely made the mental switch from one language to the next and I had put...

```
$return_array = [];
```

... as my array initialization there.  The PHP log got me pointed in the right direction.

Thanks for the help everyone.